# Moving turtlebot with own implementation of Astar

Tags: navigation, turtlebot, ros-kinetic, move-base, pathplanning

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have managed to use turtlebot3 (gazebo and Rviz) to create a map and use its data to implement an Astar algorithm(in python).The result is the series of (x,y) coordinates to which robot should move. But now i am confused which topic to publish into to tell robot to move to those places in that sequence.I know there is move_base package but it uses its own path planners,i have read that you can create your own plugin but i feel i might be overthinking and it might be some other way.So i have two questions:

1- Which topic or topics to use to publish these locations?

2-My results are in coordinates system,do i have to convert them back into world coordinates?
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285632/moving-turtlebot-with-own-implementation-of-astar/) by [az](https://answers.ros.org/users/33491/az/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-03-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should change the default global planner instead of publishing your own goals (to answer your question, there are 3 topics using goals : `move_base/goal`, `move_base/current_goal`, `move_base_simple/goal` )

You should find how to do it here [#q188257](https://answers.ros.org/question/188257/ros-navigation-stack-changing-global-planner/).

You can define the global planner in the [move_base.launch.xml](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_apps/blob/hydro/turtlebot_navigation/launch/includes/move_base.launch.xml) (this is an exemple from turtlebot navigation) by adding this in the launch file inside the `node` tag : `<param name="base_global_planner" value="carrot_planner/CarrotPlanner"/>` or define the `base_global_planner` param in a yaml file.

And yes I think you should convert them to into the world coordinates because in general the algorithms are based on coordinates given by the costmap.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2018-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0